# Change default task format to html Outlook 2013

Tags: tasks, microsoft-outlook-2013

I used to be able to paste images straight off the clipboard into the main Outlook task window  in older versions of Outlook.   Now I get a "Pictures will be lost" message, and can't find anywhere to change the format to RTF or HTML.

Any ideas?

Comment: It'll need to be RTF if anything, as the Tasks don't support HTML.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, and anybody else.  I'm still stuck with this.  I made a little video here as I happen to install 2010 on an old laptop as my new laptop packed up.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVv2zZ8XqBw